# Performance Issue After Upgarding to angular 13

Tags: angular, angular13

After Upgarding Project from Angular 8 to Angular 13
main.js not Caching in browser that make Refresh takes more time than previous Version

How could make main.js Caching?

[image]

Comment: Do you have this issues during development or in production?

Comment: both development and Production

Comment: Are you sure that caching is set up properly on your production web server? Also, did you maybe disable cache in the developer tools? I have doubts that this is Angular's fault.

Comment: @JSONDerulo
Yes, I am sure.
when i switch to the branch which has the previous version before upgrading and publish it works and caches again.

Comment: So I think some changes in upgrading , causing that!